# Coding Changes in Variables in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation, recode, data-management

I am working with data that looks like this:

```
   ID Year Variable_of_Interest
1   a 2000                   0
2   a 2001                   0
3   a 2002                   0
4   a 2003                   0
5   a 2004                   0
6   a 2005                   1
7   a 2006                   1
8   a 2007                   1
9   a 2008                   1
10  a 2009                   1
11  b 2000                   0
12  b 2001                   0
13  b 2002                   0
14  b 2003                   1
15  b 2004                   1
16  b 2005                   1
17  b 2006                   1
18  b 2007                   1
19  b 2008                   1
20  b 2009                   1
21  c 2000                   0
22  c 2001                   0
23  c 2002                   0
24  c 2003                   0
25  c 2004                   0
26  c 2005                   0
27  c 2006                   1
28  c 2007                   1
29  c 2008                   1
30  c 2009                   1
31  d 2000                   0
32  d 2001                   0
33  d 2002                   1
34  d 2003                   1
35  d 2004                   1
36  d 2005                   1
37  d 2006                   0
38  d 2007                   0
39  d 2008                   0
40  d 2009                   0
```

The unit of analysis is ID. The IDs repeat across each year in the data. The `variable of interest` column represents changes to the IDs, wherein some years they are a 0 and other years they are a 1

I want to create an additional column that codes changes (defined as going from 0 to 1) in the `Variable_of_Interest` at the year before and after the change, while also ignoring changes from (1 to 0) (as seen when the ID is equal to "d").

Any code that can help me achieve this solution would be greatly appreciated!

Perferability I'd like the data to look like this:

```
   ID Year Variable_of_Interest Solution
1   a 2000                   0       -5
2   a 2001                   0       -4
3   a 2002                   0       -3
4   a 2003                   0       -2
5   a 2004                   0       -1
6   a 2005                   1        0
7   a 2006                   1        1
8   a 2007                   1        2
9   a 2008                   1        3
10  a 2009                   1        4
11  b 2000                   0       -3
12  b 2001                   0       -2
13  b 2002                   0       -1
14  b 2003                   1        0
15  b 2004                   1        1
16  b 2005                   1        2
17  b 2006                   1        3
18  b 2007                   1        4
19  b 2008                   1        5
20  b 2009                   1        6
21  c 2000                   0       -6
22  c 2001                   0       -5
23  c 2002                   0       -4
24  c 2003                   0       -3
25  c 2004                   0       -2
26  c 2005                   0       -1
27  c 2006                   1        0
28  c 2007                   1        1
29  c 2008                   1        2
30  c 2009                   1        3
31  d 2000                   0       -2
32  d 2001                   0       -1
33  d 2002                   1        0
34  d 2003                   1        1
35  d 2004                   1        2
36  d 2005                   1        3
37  d 2006                   0       NA
38  d 2007                   0       NA
39  d 2008                   0       NA
40  d 2009                   0       NA
```

Here is the replication code:

```
ID <- c(rep("a",10), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10), rep("d", 10)); length(ID)
Year <- rep(seq(2000,2009, 1), 4)
Variable_of_Interest <- c(rep(0,5), rep(1, 5), 
                         rep(0,3), rep(1, 7), 
                         rep(0,6), rep(1, 4),
                         rep(0,2), rep(1, 4), rep(0,4))


data.frame(ID, Year, Variable_of_Interest)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a function :

```
library(dplyr)

get_sequence <- function(x) {
  inds <- which(x == 1 & lag(x) == 0)[1]
  vals <- seq_along(x) - inds
  inds <- which(x == 0 & lag(x) == 1)[1]
  if(!is.na(inds))  vals[inds:length(x)] <- NA
  return(vals)
}
```

and apply it for each `ID` :

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Solution = get_sequence(Variable_of_Interest)) 

#   ID Year Variable_of_Interest Solution
#1   a 2000                    0       -5
#2   a 2001                    0       -4
#3   a 2002                    0       -3
#4   a 2003                    0       -2
#5   a 2004                    0       -1
#6   a 2005                    1        0
#7   a 2006                    1        1
#8   a 2007                    1        2
#9   a 2008                    1        3
#10  a 2009                    1        4
#11  b 2000                    0       -3
#...
#...
#33  d 2002                    1        0
#34  d 2003                    1        1
#35  d 2004                    1        2
#36  d 2005                    1        3
#37  d 2006                    0       NA
#38  d 2007                    0       NA
#39  d 2008                    0       NA
#40  d 2009                    0       NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! What would the code be, if I wanted the NA's to count (in negative numbers with increasing values) the years from the last one. Such that, the solution would replace the NA's in the example with (-1, -2, -3, -4). Thanks. again!

Comment: @SharifAmlani replace `NA` with `-seq_along(inds:length(x))` ?